# Flutter rootBundle loadString CSV FormatException

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

I am facing a problem with the rootBundle loadString method. I am trying to load a csv file exported from external source. If I open and then close the file with excel, everything is working fine. I have checked the encoding which is not the issue, maybe I'm wrong... Still I am suspecting a blank line with newline at the end of the file.

here's my code:

```
  initClient() async {
    var myCsvFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/csv2.txt');

    var encoded = utf8.encode(myCsvFile);
    var decoded = utf8.decode(encoded);
    var rowAsListValues =
        const CsvToListConverter(fieldDelimiter: '\t', eol: '\n')
            .convert(decoded);
    var parsedList = [];
    for (var items in rowAsListValues) {
      if (items[4] < 0) {
        parsedList.add(items);
      }
    }

    return parsedList;
  }
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB91X.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybzpL.png)[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPeB.png)

Comment: Hi There. You need to add more details as to what is the exact error you are facing. Also try to share a csv for a minimal reproducible demo.

Comment: Can you post the full exception your are getting?

Comment: sorry, I just added more details. Please do see the pictures. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @PixelUvw Are you sure the file is encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: Also, your code does not make much sense when you do encode and decode right after. Just use the string `myCsvFile` directly and make sure your file (assets/csv2.txt) is saved as UTF-8 on the disk.

Comment: The thing is when I open the csv file in VsCode and remove the last line, then hot-reload, everything's working. What am I missing?

Comment: @julemand101 Yes the file is encoded as UTF-8. Without the encoding and decoding nothing shows up!

Comment: @PixelUvw Ok, we need you to upload an example of you CSV file which can reproduce your problem.